# Eclipse Problems View Double Click

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a double click mouse event for the Problems View in Eclipse. I am creating a plugin that needs to get the data about the problem the user double clicks in the problems view.

A few details: I am coding in java but the user will be using the CDT plugin for coding in C/C++. So far I have been unable to get the data from the current selection in the problems view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible as it requires Java access to the viewer in the view.

You can add a command for the current line in the problems view with the `org.eclipse.ui.commands`/`org.eclipse.ui.handlers`/`org.eclipse.ui.menus` combination.